# Find a file within any a specific folder with subfolders using PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

I am stuck with the following, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a folder tree like follows:

```
images/collections/
```

Within the collections folder there could be numerous subfolders

```
images/collections/collection1, images/collections/collection2
```

Images are named like

```
imageProductCode-something.jpg
```

What i am trying to do is pass one variable which is my product code to a script which then finds the file in any of the folders and returns its path...

```
images/collections/collection3/imageProductCode-something.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
function getImageDirectory($iId) {
    $oDirectory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/to/images/");
    $oIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($oDirectory);
    foreach($oIterator as $oFile) {
        if ($oFile->getFilename() == 'imageProductCode-' . $iId . '.jpg') {
            return $oFile->getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap it into a custom `FilterIterator` or use a `RecursiveRegexIterator` and you get my upvote. Also, you dont need the check for `isFile` because the default behavior of the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is to return leaves only, so `$oFile` will always be files.

Answer (score 0):

You could check all your collections:

```
$collections = array('collection1', 'collection2', 'collection3');

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
  if (file_exists('/path/to/collections/'.$collection.'/'.$productCode.'.jpg')) {
    ... do your thing ...
    break;
  }
}
```

Depending on the size of your catalogue, it might be faster to create a database (flatfile or MySQL) to lookup the location of the image for a specific product code.

Comment: This looks like a very good idea, I take your point about adding a script to list locations

Comment: if you want database for that, i suggest sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of PHP which is < 5.3, you might need to write the recursion yourself.
Main methods your would like to follow:

1. opendir
2. readdir
3. is_dir
4. is_file

Start at the root of your images, check every entry. If it's a directory, check the directory.
Seems like a lot of work, so if you're looking at large directories and image collections, you might want to look into either the unix command or db linking, as suggested above.

Another way would be to have the directories connected logically to the images, so that you can tell from the name (or other property) of the image in which directory to look.

Good luck,

Yishai

Comment: The SPL (and specifically DirectoryIterators) were added in PHP5, although they can no longer be disabled after 5.3.  Not correcting this answer, just adding to your point.